# Get media from two posts with same image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Let's say I create a new post and upload an image to it. Now I can get the image's source URL by calling `get_attached_media` with the post's ID or by calling the API at `/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=$ID`.

If I create a new post and use the same image, how can I get the source URL for the image from the ID of the second post?

Answer (score 0):

get_attached_media() accepts a [post_id as an argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/), ie:

```
get_attached_media('image',$post_id);
```

Comment: Thought it was clear from my question, but I know that. The problem is, in my example, if I use the post ID of post 2, it won't return the image's source URL because it is attached to post 1.

Comment: So why not just pass the post_id of post1 then?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. What code have you tried? Perhaps by posting your current attempts, we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let's say I send a request to my API to get images from post 2 and there are 100 posts. It doesn't return any image URLs, because the image I used in post 2 is attached to some other post. In this situation I have no way of knowing which post the image I am trying to get the URL of belongs to, so I can't just call the API at `/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=$ID` - or in your case - call `get_attached_media('image',$post_id);`, because I don't know the correct ID. I hope it makes sense.